# Text is printed at weird positions in some (sub)sections

Tags: pdftex, geometry

I'm writing a realively normal document. I just adjusted it to print it double sided. Now a few pages have weird placement of text and images. Notice that the text should be directly under the section header and the image directly below it.
[image]

The source for the page:

```
\subsection{Cartridge}
The newly designed cartridge is half the height of proof of concept's cartridge while holding the same amount of plastic tube. The force needed to pull the plastic out of the cartridge is the same, as described in chapter \ref{subsec:des2_cart}. The difference between size is shown in figure \ref{fig:cartimprove}. The cartridge does not damage the plastic bag. The cartridge is found to be easy to replace thanks to the sliding the mechanism, although it is advised to test this mechanism with other test subjects. It should, however, be noted that there is quite some space needed between to cartridge and the sealer mechanism to get the cartridge out. This space is needed because the opening between the seal beams is too small for the cartridge to pass through. So to get the cartridge out you will need to tilt it quite a bit. Figure \ref{fig:carttilt} visualizes this.\\

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{img/cartimprove.PNG}
        \caption{Size reduction of new cartridge}
        \label{fig:cartimprove}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

and my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}


\usepackage[margin=2cm, twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

% References %
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
citestyle=numeric,
sorting=none,
hyperref=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

% Images % 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% pro and cons lists*
\newcommand*\MyPitem{%
\item[\textbf{\color{green}\scalebox{1}{+}}]}
\newcommand*\MyCitem{%
\item[\textbf{\color{red}\scalebox{1.1}{-}}]}

% Page layout%

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{\slshape title}
\fancyhead[LO, RE]{\slshape name}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\parindent 0ex
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,shapes,arrows}
% needed for BB
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[fitpaper=false, pages=-, noautoscale=true]{inc/frontpage.pdf}

\cleardoublepage
```

Comment: you have used `[H]` which _by design_ produces poorer spacing as it prevents floats moving to avoid bad page breaks.

Comment: twoside defaults to `\flushbottom` so tex has to try to make the page reach the bottom, hence the page, you may prefer `\raggedbottom`  (but not using `[H]` also helps.)

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick!